# How to make the same shuffle on 2 different datasets but saving the ordering of rows in both

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 data sets 1: `train_df` and 2: `test_df`.
But they are unbalanced that's why I decided to use `RandomUnderSampler` from `imblearn.under_sampling`
and I got this dataset : [This is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY3Xy.png)

You can see that there first half of it the target column consist from `0` and the second -> `1`, but I want shuffle it.
Can I use `df.sample(frac=1)` in this case ?
Take in consideration that I have already  splited  test/train  and I have to apply shuffle on both of it.
If not -> How to shuffle them simultaneously keep the ordering of them ?

This is code:

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler

train_df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Toxic_dataset/toxic_train.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Toxic_dataset/toxic_test.csv')

undersampler = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy='majority')
X_train = train_df.iloc[:, 0:-1]
y_train = train_df.iloc[:,-1]
X_test = test_df.iloc[:, 0:-1]
y_test = test_df.iloc[:,-1]

X_train, y_train = undersampler.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
X_test, y_test = undersampler.fit_resample(X_test,y_test)

X_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train)
y_train = pd.DataFrame(y_train)
X_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test)
y_test = pd.DataFrame(y_test)
```

This are dataframe images:
[enter image description here][2]

Comment: Please, add a minimal code to reproduce and expected result.

Comment: I added minimal code to reproduce, but I don't know how to add dataframe that is imported

Comment: Why don't you merge the two df and then split them again with https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Answer (score 0):

Make an indexing array, and shuffle the indexing array, and then order each of your data arrays based on it.

```
x = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])       # data 1
y = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])  # data 2

i = np.arange(len(x))  # the indexing array
np.random.shuffle(i)

x0 = x[i]
y0 = y[i]
```

Here are the results:

```
[0 1 2 3 4]            # i
[1 2 0 3 4]            # i shuffled
[20 30 10 40 50]       # x0
['b' 'c' 'a' 'd' 'e']  # y0
```